# Joint Posterior Distribution

Tags: posterior, beta-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

I have 4 groups, each has a probability of developing gout (Bernoulli distribution), with a total of 400 individuals. I am confused how to derive and present the joint posterior distribution for each group. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to assume that the expected proportions in the groups have something to do with each other? If you think that that's not the case, i.e. when you see the data for 3 of the groups, it would not change what you expect (or you want to assume that it does not) for the 4th group, then you simply specify separate independent priors and get independent posteriors. The joint posterior density is then simply the product of the 4 posterior densities. In this scenario, you get nice analytical solutions using conjugate updating, if you assume your priors are beta distributions or mixtures of beta distributions.

If you assume that the groups might somehow be similar, then you may want a hierarchical model (or some empirical Bayes approach), in which case there might not be  a closed form posterior depending on how you assume the expected proportions vary across groups and whether you e.g. know some ordering (e.g. group A should have a higher expected proportions than group B).